# ImportError: cannot import name 'Flags' from 'pandas'

Tags: pandas, modin

I ran into the below when trying to import pandas from modin on mac os

`import modin.pandas as pd`. what is the possible fix for this?

error traceback

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-7e7b44bd7fd7> in <module>
----> 1 import modin.pandas as pd

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/modin/pandas/__init__.py in <module>
     26     )
     27 
---> 28 from pandas import (
     29     eval,
     30     cut,

ImportError: cannot import name 'Flags' from 'pandas' (/Users/mac/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, pandas version that you use is old enough. `Flags` appeared in pandas since 1.2.1 version. In order to get the latest versions of Modin and pandas, you can do the following:

```
pip uninstall modin # this removes Modin and its dependencies
pip install modin # this installs Modin 0.9.1 with pandas 1.2.3
```